# How to Test User Consent Status (GoogleMobileAds UMP SDK)

Tags: objective-c, admob, google-mobile-ads, user-messaging-platform

I'm in the process of integrating the [GoogleMobileAds & User Messenger Platform SDK](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start) for iOS.

I understand it offers a way for users to **consent** or **not consent** inside the EEA.

Firstly you test to see if consent is required:

```
UMPFormStatus formStatus = UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance
                                 .formStatus;
                         if (formStatus == UMPFormStatusAvailable) {
                           [self loadForm];
                         }
...
```

The Admob guide says you can serve non-personalised ads as follows:

```
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
GADExtras *extras = [[GADExtras alloc] init];
extras.additionalParameters = @{@"npa": @"1"};  //this being the key line
[request registerAdNetworkExtras:extras];
```

If the user consents, ads can be loaded fine, as GoogleMobileAds default is to serve personalised ads...

However, if a user does choose **not** to consent, how do we programmatically test the consent status before loading Ads? Or does the GoogleMobileAds monitor this inside Admob and only serve non-personalised ads based on the users input?

I haven't found an answer to this on Stack or Github etc.
Thank you for your time.

**Edit**:
I have since discovered that if a user doesn't consent, no ads are shown... But a test to check consent would still be helpful, as you could manually load non-personalised ads (npa)... But I can't find how to test the consent, so the question above, still stands. Thank you.

Comment: add GADDelayAppMeasurementInit to info.plist https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/ios/quick-start#delay_app_measurement_optional

Comment: @AmodGokhale Other than delaying metrics, would you mind explaining how that would help showing non-personalised ads to those who don't consent? Thank you.

Comment: this is from link above "By default, the Google Mobile Ads SDK initializes app measurement and begins sending user-level event data to Google immediately when the app starts. This initialization behavior ensures you can enable AdMob user metrics without making additional code changes. "

Comment: So i usually don't load ads sdk immediately on first launch of the app... maybe give some time before user accepts / declines consent. Alternatively you can check for consent flag... but setting above flag and not immediately loading ads on first launch should take care of your requirement

Comment: @AmodGokhale Thank you for the reply. The UMP SDK doesn't offer a consent flag, so there's no way of knowing if the user has consented or not. So are you saying adding this delay (so Ads are loaded after consent has be denied) will ensure non-personalised ads are served? Sorry if I'm still misunderstanding. I was under the impression if the user doesn't consent, no ads will be served. Thank you again

Comment: that is not correct... taking consent is not googles responsibility. Developer has to design app so that it follows guidelines of admob. if user doesn't provide any consent - By default, ad requests to Google serve personalized ads, with ad selection based on the user's previously collected data. Source - third para in this link - https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent

Comment: @AmodGokhale I never suggested it's wasn't the devs responsibility? I'm saying there's no way of knowing whether the user consented. GoogleMobileAds or UMP SDK doesn't include a public consent flag, therefore when `do not consent` is selected, non-personalised ads can't be served. Google's GDPR Legacy Consent SDK offered this consent flag (so non-personalised ads could be served in this situation). Your Source confirms this. So my question is still how do we request non-personalised ads when the user presses "do not consent"? Currently if they "do not consent" no ads are served. Thank you.

Comment: So my question is still how do we request non-personalised ads when the user presses "do not consent"? Currently if they "do not consent" no ads are served. --- Can you please upload logs after user presses "do not consent"? In my case I can see advertisements without any issue.

Comment: specially look for error code that is returned by admob for "do not consent" test case

Answer (score 0):

After GDPR consent has been collected, you can read consent choices from local storage following the TCF v2 spec. The IABTCF_PurposeConsents key indicates consent for each of the TCF purposes.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
// Example value: "1111111111"
String purposeConsents = sharedPref.getString("IABTCF_PurposeConsents", "");
// Purposes are zero-indexed. Index 0 contains information about Purpose 1.
if (!purposeConsents.isEmpty()) {
  String purposeOneString = purposeConsents.charAt(0);
  boolean hasConsentForPurposeOne = purposeOneString.equals("1");
}
```

See https://developers.google.com/admob/android/privacy/gdpr#how_to_read_consent_choices